# How to get function codes for SAP GUI context menus?

Tags: automated-tests, sap-gui, silktest

I am automating tests of our SAP GUI application using Silk4J (16.0.1.7470). There is a tree where I selected a node. I can open the context menu programmatically with [SapTree.nodeContextMenu()](http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.borland.silktest.silk4net.doc%2Flangref%2FSAP%2FNodeContextMenuMethodSapTree_ref.html).

Now I want to simulate a click onto one of the context menu items. It seems that this can be done with [SapTree.selectContextMenuItem()](http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.borland.silktest.silk4net.doc%2Flangref%2FSAP%2FSelectContextMenuItemMethodISapContextMenuable_ref.html). However, this function needs a function code.

**How do I get a list of function codes that are available on the context menu?**

I have tried [SapTree.selectContextMenuItemByText()](http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.borland.silktest.silk4net.doc%2Flangref%2FSAP%2FSelectContextMenuItemByTextMethodISapContextMenuable_ref.html) but that resulted in the exception.

> ```
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Error executing 'SelectContextMenuItemByText'. An
>     unexpected COM exception occurred at SAP Frontend Server (The method got an
>     invalid argument.)
>   at com.borland.silktest.jtf.internal.Agent.convertException(Agent.java:294)
>   at com.borland.silktest.jtf.internal.Agent.invoke(Agent.java:394)
>   at com.borland.silktest.jtf.AbstractTestObject.invoke(AbstractTestObject.java:462)
>   at com.microfocus.silktest.jtf.sap.SapTree.selectContextMenuItemByText(SapTree.java:1650)
> ...
> ```

I have also tried [SapContextMenu.select()](http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.borland.silktest.silk4net.doc%2Flangref%2FSAP%2FSelectMethodSapMenu_ref.html), but there is no parameter to that method, so I wonder which item it will select.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Using SAP Script Recorder

One way of getting the function code is to record the action with the SAP Script Recording and Playback (screenshot in German).

[image: SAP Script Recording and Playback]

Open the recorded script in Notepad and find the action

```
session.findById(...).selectContextMenuItem "DELETE_RELATION"
```

`"DELETE_RELATION"` is the function code you're looking for.

### Using Silk4J

Context menus in SAP are a collection of context menus. This could explain the `select()` method without parameters. That probably works well on leaf context menu items.

To dump all function codes programatically, you can use the function [getName()](http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.borland.silktest.silk4net.doc%2Flangref%2FSAP%2FNamePropertySapComponent_ref.html) and call it on all context menus. `getText()` gets the human readable text.

```
List<SapContextMenu> menus = tree.getDesktop().findAll("//SapContextMenu");
for(SapContextMenu menu:menus){
    try{
        logger.debug("Function code: "+menu.getName());
        logger.debug("Displayed text: "+menu.getText());
        logger.debug("");
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        logger.debug(e); // Didn't happen for me
    }                                                        
}
```